# How do I deploy to Google Compute Engine using the Ruby stack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-compute-engine

I'm totally lost trying to deploy a demo Rails app to *my-app-name*.appspot.com. I set up a project in the Developers Console and deployed the Ruby stack on my VM. I would have thought I just need to configure the web server's default site such that the DocumentRoot is the public folder of my Rails app (from /etc/apache2/sites-available/default):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-app-name.appspot.com
    DocumentRoot /apps/my-app-name/public
    <Directory /apps/my-app-name/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Since I'm aiming for the *my-app-name*.appspot.com space and not using a separate domain, I'm guessing the ServerName and ServerAlias settings are not needed in this case. Now when I visit my target appspot.com address I get a 404 error:

**Not Found - The requested URL / was not found on this server.**

The logs show that Phusion Passenger is in fact listening to requests. And when I visit the numbered IP address for my project I still get Apache's default index page. Obviously  there's a crucial part of the picture I'm not seeing, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `dig my-app-name.appspot.com` say, i.e, what exactly is mapping that DNS name to the public IP of your GCE instance?  I had only heard of appspot.com used for google **app** engine, not **compute** engine, but maybe I'm just missing something here!

Comment: +1 to what @AlexMartelli said. You're running on a Compute Engine VM but using the hostname that's defined by App Engine, which are not compatible. Perhaps you want to look into [custom runtimes on Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes) instead? Alternatively, if you really want to run on Compute Engine, you have to bring your own domain name and add a DNS record for your external IP address so that your hostname resolves properly.

Comment: @AlexMartelli Thanks guys, that did finally occur to me, and you have now confirmed that fact. I'll just have to access my project using the IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the posters who commented, I now understand that I was barking up the wrong tree. The appspot.com domain is not compatible with compute engine; I will have to access my project via the IP address.

Also, since I was only trying to put up a test app as proof of concept, **I needed to set the Rails environment to `development`**. I was frustrated until I found these instructions (Step 6): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Once the required time has passed, please accept this answer to clearly show the issue is closed and resolved -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Detailed instructions how to deploy Ruby on Rails on Google Compute Engine**:
http://startup-with-gae.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-deploy-ruby-on-rails-application.html